# Shadow on the top of Indicator height within the tab

Tags: android, tabs, shadow

I am not able to show the shadow of the indicator above the indicatior height within the tabs. i am using the karim library for material tabs,where i apply elevation but that does not help.How can i accheive shadow within the tab?

**layout**

```
 <io.karim.MaterialTabs
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:mtIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryRed"
        app:mtIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:mtPaddingMiddle="false"
        app:mtSameWeightTabs="true"
        app:mtTabPaddingLeftRight="10dp" />
```

**test drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:left="-11dp" android:right="-11dp" android:top="-11dp">
                <shape>

                    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryRed" />

                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#00fafafa" android:startColor="#88d66f67" android:type="linear" />

                    <corners android:radius="2dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

**java**

```
class StarterMenuAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public StarterMenuAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 1) {
            LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
            return loginFragment;
        } else {
            RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();
            return registerFragment;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }
}
```

**want to achieve**
[image]

**what i got**
[image]

> how can shadow within the tab be achieved?

Comment: try android:elevation="-20dp"

Comment: @AkshayKatariya thats does not help akshay

Answer (score 0):

It is similar as you want,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:left="-8dp" android:right="-8dp" android:top="-8dp">
                <shape>

                    <stroke android:width="7dp" android:color="@color/red" />

                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#00fafafa" android:startColor="#88d66f67" android:type="linear" />

                    <corners android:radius="2dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: make drawable and put this code inside....and set drawable as a background of your selected tab

Comment: i am confused where to do .i have updated my solution ,check

Comment: but where you have used test drawable??

Comment: are you able to add drawable instead of "app:mtIndicatorColor"?? is there any property??

Comment: then remove "app:mtIndicatorColor" and add property to set drawable. Your selected tab will be look as my edited answer.

Comment: there is one proble in adding the drawable.it is always visible to both tab.

Comment: which property do you use??

Comment: when i add that drawable as background

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160182/discussion-between-ghimire-and-dhruv-patel).